# How to query data that's present in one tab, but not in another?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a sheet with three tabs. One tab for subscriptions (containing a name, in this case an unique username + date + some personal information), one tab for unsubscriptions (with the same username as in subscriptions) and one tab where I want to show all active subscriptions.

An active subscription is when the username is present in subscriptions, but not in unsubscriptions. There is a possibility that the same username subscribes again, in which case there are multiple entries in the two tabs. In that case, it's active when the subscriptiondate is more recent than the last unsub.

The structure for both sub & unsubs-tab are the same, except for the headertext (Sub.date vs Unsub.date for example).

I now have a query which returns all the subscriptions + information needed for the "Active subs" tab. I don't know where to start for the "filtering" with the Unsubs-tab..

I expect a Query-like output with all active subscriptions with the information from the subscriptionstab I need. The information is in different columns, so subscriptiondate, address and so on are located in for example column E & F, while the unique username is in column B.

Answer (score 0):

Might need a little adjustment but seems worth a try, in a spare column:

```
 =if(and(maxifs(E:E,B:B,B1)=E1,maxifs(E:E,B:B,B1)>maxifs(UnSub!E:E,UnSub!B:B,B1)),"Y",)
```

then select on the basis of the presence of 'Y'.

The logic is supposed to be:

*Is this the row that contains the most recent subscription date for this individual AND
is this individual's most recent subscription date more recent than the most recent unsubscription date for this individual?*

So could be shortened a little to:

```
=if(and(E1=maxifs(E:E,B:B,B1),E1>maxifs(UnSub!E:E,UnSub!B:B,B1)),"Y",)
```

Or:

*Is this the most recent date for this individual across both sheets?*